# Reset HightChart After a week Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I am using HighCharts on my web application, for visual reference. I fetch data from my database for each user to draw a line.

The problem I am having is that new point is added everyday and after lets say **2-3 weeks** there is so many points mapped that the graph becomes hell and it also affect the web app performance.

I would like someone to help me how to make the graph reset after a week or remove the oldest point from the graph and add new point.If this is possible as I have spend a lot of time trying to come up with a solution but with no luck graph is just keep growing.

Printscreen:

[image]
Notice how the graph goes beyond predefined days.

My PHP & Mysql $ JavaScript Code:

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#home_manager').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: '',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Emails Sent'
                },
                plotLines: [
                    {
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }
                ]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            <?php


        class ManagerStats{

            public function con()
        {
            require_once('connect.php');
            $DB = new dbConnect();
            return $DB->connect();
        }

            public function teamChart(){




            $sql2 = "SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.first_name, group_concat( tbl_statistics.sta_count ) AS data_for_user
            FROM tbl_user,tbl_statistics
            WHERE tbl_user.user_id = tbl_statistics.user_id
            GROUP BY tbl_user.user_id";

            $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $sql2);



            if($query){

                $data = "";
                $data .="series: [";
                foreach($query as $v){

                    $data .= "{

                        name: '".$v['first_name']."',
                        data: [".$v['data_for_user']."]

                },";
            }
            $data .="]";
            echo $data;


        }


        }
    }

    $team = new ManagerStats(); $team->teamChart();


?>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a timestamp or datetime column which allow you to know when a row was added to the table `tbl_statistics`?

Comment: yes it is called: sat_date

Comment: Limit your results in your SQL query to only the current weeks set of data. I would also recommend adding some method to view historic weekly data if that is desired.

Comment: Your data is string not array. If you add only brackets, it doenst mean that it is array, so prepare your data as arrays then use return json and clean your code. Instaed of mix javascript with class definition and object definition.

Answer (score 1):

Why not limit your data on the SQL query?

Something like:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.first_name, group_concat( tbl_statistics.sta_count ) AS data_for_user
            FROM tbl_user,tbl_statistics
            WHERE tbl_user.user_id = tbl_statistics.user_id
            GROUP BY tbl_user.user_id
            ORDER BY sat_date DESC LIMIT 7";
```

or perhaps datediff to restrict it? something like this for the last 7 days:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.first_name, group_concat( tbl_statistics.sta_count ) AS data_for_user
            FROM tbl_user,tbl_statistics
            WHERE tbl_user.user_id = tbl_statistics.user_id
            AND Datediff(now(), sat_date) <= 7
            GROUP BY tbl_user.user_id";
```

Comment: HI I really like the first suggested solution...Looks Neat.. But when I add this line to my SQL no effect is visible everything remains the same

Comment: OK I c what happens the LIMIT in the first suggested query does not limit the number of figures for each user but the users its self, if I released this as I did limit 1 and only one name appeared.....

Comment: Limit will restrict the return to only X rows so yes, if you limit to 1, 1 row is returned.  Datediff will return only those dates that fall within the range.  How your table is structured will determine which to use. See this fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31495/18

Comment: what I need to do is to DESC all the group_concat results and limit them